# How to loop through my html and inject text if a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to write a function that generates a span tag and injects some text if a condition is met but i keep receiving `[object HTMLSpanElement]`. Am i using innerText and innerHTML incorrectly?

### JavaScript:

```
function checkBlankReviews(){

  var reviewTexts = document.querySelectorAll('p.text');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(reviewTexts, function (item) { // iterate the elements

      if (item.innerText === '') {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerText = "No Reviews";
          item.innerHTML = span;
          
          console.log('no reviews for: ' + item.innerHTML);
      } 

    return item;
    
  });


}
```

Here is my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fovixi/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this:

```
item.innerHTML = span;
```

`innerHTML` expects a string, so this is basically going to become

```
item.innerHTML = span.toString();
```

Which is where you end up getting `[object HTMLSpanElement]`. Instead, it seems you just wanted the html of the span element you have constructed. [`outerHTML`<sup>***MDN***</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) will solve that for you.

```
item.innerHTML = span.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Haven't used outerHTML before. Works great. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create a string, with the html you need, and insert it into the node:

```
function checkBlankReviews(){

  var reviewTexts = document.querySelectorAll('p.text');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(reviewTexts, function (item) { 

      if (item.innerText === '') {
          item.innerHTML = "<span>No Reviews</span>";

          console.log('no reviews for: ' + item.innerHTML);
      } 

    return item;

  });


}

checkBlankReviews();
```

Another option is just to set the text as the `innerText` of the `<p>` element:

```
function checkBlankReviews(){

  var reviewTexts = document.querySelectorAll('p.text');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(reviewTexts, function (item) { 

      if (item.innerText === '') {
          item.innerText = "No Reviews";

          console.log('no reviews for: ' + item.innerText);
      } 

    return item;

  });


}

checkBlankReviews();
```

Comment: While using appendChild is a valid way of getting an element constructed in script placed inside of an element on the page, one issue with that approach in this situation is that if the function is being called on some event then many of those elements will end up being appended in the same place.

Comment: I totally agree, that's why I offered a 2nd option.